# Covert image from png to jpg using Carrierwave

Tags: ruby, carrierwave

I am using Carrierwave to upload pictures.  I want to convert PNGs to JPEGs when they are uploade to S3 using Fog

I have tried writing a method in the uploader like so:

```
  def covert_image
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.strip
      img.format('jpeg')
      img.combine_options do |c|
        c.quality "80"
        c.depth "8"
        c.interlace "plane"
      end
      img
    end
  end
```

This does no work however.  I have Googled around for ways to do this conversion but I am unable to find any examples.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use minimagick? If so, try swapping

```
img.format('jpeg')
```

to

```
img.convert('jpeg')
```

From https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/carrierwave/CarrierWave%2FMiniMagick%3Aconvert